# 'Something is arrived' - is this use of a participle as an adjective acceptable?

Tags: past-participles, archaic-language, transitivity, adjectivals

As I know, intransitive verb can't be used in passive voice.  Arrive is an intransitive verb. I wonder if "be +arrived" is still understandable and available?

> Something will be arriving tomorrow. (**arriving** as progressive participle adjective)
>
> Something is arrived. (**arrived** as participle adjective)

I know that it can't be passive voice, but the sentence structure is same as passive voice.

Are these two grammatically correct?

Comment: _I hope the package will be arriving tomorrow. Otherwise, it'll be too late for Christmas!_ (Just a seasonal way to acknowledge that, yes, "be arriving tomorrow" can be a valid construct.)

Answer (score 5):

*BE arriving* is grammatical: the progressive construction.

*BE arrived* was at one time grammatical.

Through Early Modern English, most verbs of motion (*come, go, arrive, depart, move*, and so forth) used *BE* instead of *HAVE* for the perfect construction.

> Joy to the world! The Lord is come.

But that use gradually disappeared during the 18th and 19th centuries; today *HAVE* is the only perfect auxiliary. You should not use *BE* to construct perfects; say *Something **has** arrived*.

Note, however, that a few past participles act as frank adjectives—*gone*, for instance—and these can be used with *BE* to indicate a state rather than an action: *Jack is gone now; we expect him back tomorrow.*

Comment: Can I say "arrived product"? Arrived (past participles) to modify product

Comment: Use the word *delivered* instead - *the delivered product, the product is delivered.*